# Как сделать адаптивную разметку?

Tags: xml, button, android, разметка

Здравствуйте, сделал разметку, но она не эффективна на разных разрешениях экранов, т.к. я задавал ширину и высоту и расположение явно. Подскажите, как мне можно это подправить?

Вот картинка на результат:

[image: Imgur]

Вот код xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundpattern"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="ru.mitasov.mnemotehnika.GameActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="144dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/NewGameWordsButton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
        android:text="@string/Level1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
        android:text="@string/Level2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
        android:text="@string/Level3" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout1"        
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
        android:text="@string/Level4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
        android:text="@string/Level5" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout2"        
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
        android:text="@string/Level6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
        android:text="@string/Level7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
        android:text="@string/Level8" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю вам отказаться от RelativeLayout таким образом

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
        >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
                />
        <Button android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
                />
        <Button android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
                />

        <Button android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
                />
        <Button android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
                />
        <Button android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень выручили!