# Отступы между кнопками

Tags: xml, android, разметка

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно осуществить отступы между кнопками в XML? Я задаю напрямую координаты кнопок, но на больших экранах все сбивается.

То есть я постоянно отступаю от левого краю, но это не эффективно:

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/NewGameWordsButton"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
                android:text="@string/Level1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
                android:text="@string/Level2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
                android:text="@string/Level3" />
```

Comment: Добавьте скрин или схемотично нарисуйте, что Вы хотите получить на экране.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это старый вопрос, который переформулирован автором в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/355166/ и там получен ответ

Answer (score 0):

android:padding, android:margin

Answer (score 0):

Из изложенного я вижу 3 кнопки, которые будут привязаны к левому краю (положение задаёт marginLeft).

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/NewGameWordsButton"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
            android:text="@string/Level1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/NewGameWordsButton"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
            android:text="@string/Level2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
            android:text="@string/Level3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

в values в файле dimens добавить строку

```
 <dimen name="margin_left">20dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Опять же я не совсем понимаю. В вашем примере, как и в моем мы отталкиваемся от левого края, т.е. если запустить приложение на большем экране, то все кнопки у нас останутся слева, а справа будет пустота. Я бы хотел как нибудь сделать отступы между кнопками, и все равно к какому они краю будут привязаны, главное, чтобы на разных экранах одинаково выглядело.

Comment: Спасибо всем за попытки помочь, проблема решена, помоги здесь:
http://hashcode.ru/questions/355166/android-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83